# apache shiro: use google+ for authorizing my REST service

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, google-plus, shiro

In my android app, I want to set up google+ for authentication.

My android app also needs to talk to my own REST API.

Is it possible to use the token returned by google+

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in

for authenticating my own REST API using Shiro?

I seem to see some connection but couldn't fully flush out how to do that with Shiro.

Thanks!